# Bootstrap 4 Solid Background Color Banding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 (beta 2) and I have a simple

```
<div class="bg-dark"></div>
```

I also have CSS

```
.bg-dark{
    height: 300px;
}
```

The background color is filled, but there is weird banding through it. I checked an it appears for me in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Does anyone know a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Tested on Bootply ( https://www.bootply.com/jIO9f1T3gu ) but don't see any banding on macOS Safari, Chrome, or Firefox.

Comment: Maybe your graphics card is dying? :P

Comment: Not the graphics card, it's fixed to the div and doesn't appear anywhere else

Comment: You may need to share a more complete example for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well, I literally just have a div, a class, and a height setting via css. Exactly what I have listed above.

Comment: Checked on MS Edge. No problem here! *I don't think there's any issue with Bootstrap*.

Comment: Yeah, when I checked it out further I also only appears differently at different browser window sizes. Very strange. Maybe not a code issue, maybe a browser issue only. I updated all 3 browsers and now its only appearing in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)